# strtok(): Retrieve original string+Item selected after tokenization

Tags: c, treeview, tokenize, strtok, getselection

I'm using a strtok() to break down a folder path and show it in a TreeView control, something like this:

```
->/Desktop/Songs
  ->Pop
  ->Country
```

Lets say, on the treeview, you select Folder1 (Pop) or Folder2 (Country), is it possible to retrieve the original path + selected item and show it using printf output?  So, the path "/Desktop/Songs + userselection"

```
Path Selected: /Desktop/Songs/Pop  or,
Path Selected: /Desktop/Songs/Country
```

Code:

```
HTREEITEM hItem;
HTREEITEM hsubItem;

char line[] = "/Desktop/Songs,Pop,Country" ;   
char* dir= strtok(line,",");    
printf("%s\n", dir);
hItem= treeview.InsertItem(dir); //add to a tree control as the root path or directory

while (dir!= NULL)
{
  dir= strtok(NULL,",");
  printf("%s\n", dir);
  hsubItem = treeview.InsertItem(dir, hItem); //add Pop Country below the 
  first item 
}
```

Comment: Your TreeView control should have a "GetParent()" (or equivalent) function; use that, work back to the root, then reconstruct the path string.

Comment: Make a copy of the string before you apply `strtok()` to it.

Comment: Use `strdup` to make a copy to work on.

Comment: Thank you all for your response, I am still a bit confused. Do I make a copy of the string onInit() function or OnTvnSelChangedTreeView()? I added code in the original question for a clearer understanding. thank you really guys/

Comment: You asked how to retrieve the original full string `line` before it was tokenised with `strtok()`. Simply make a copy of `line` before you split it up.

Comment: Sorry, I realized the question I was asking was kind of confusing, I updated it. Pls, check. I would like to get the path (parent)+ user selected folder and show it in a output.

Comment: The key point here is that `strtok()` is destructive -- it modifies that array on which it works.  Therefore, if you want to afterward get parts of the original string that cross token boundaries then you must either (i) reconstruct what you want from the pieces, OR (ii) keep a copy that is never subjected to tokenization, and take what you want from that.  But yes, sure, either of those can be done.